# How to set check on menu item mfc c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

how to set check on menu item mfc c++ i try this but, always unchecked menu item.

```
CString tcBuff; 
    CMenu popMenu;
    popMenu.LoadMenu(nMenuID);

    if (text.Compare(defaultconfig) == 0)
    {

        tcBuff.LoadStringW(IDC_DEFAULTREMOVE);
        popMenu.ModifyMenuW(ID_CONFIGURATION_DEFAULT,0,ID_CONFIGURATION_DEFAULT,tcBuff);
        popMenu.CheckMenuItem(IDC_DEFAULTREMOVE, MF_CHECKED || MF_BYCOMMAND);
    }
```

thanks for help.

Comment: You're modifying a new `CMenu` object, rather than the *actual* menu used in your application. Perhaps it's time to pick up [a good book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and make sure that you understand RAII?

Comment: Normally, to check menu items you do not do that. You should use a function handling the your menu item by its ID, using **ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(IDC_DEFAULTREMOVE, function)**. That **function** has a parameter **pCmdUI**. Therefore, you can do **pCmdUI->SetCheck(TRUE);** and **pCmdUI->SetText(tcBuff);** inside your **if** block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `|` operator, not the `||` operator.

You want to *combine* the `MF_CHECKED` and `MF_BYCOMMAND` bit flags, which you do with a bitwise OR operation. That requires the `|` operator.

Change your code to look like this:

```
popMenu.CheckMenuItem(IDC_DEFAULTREMOVE, MF_CHECKED | MF_BYCOMMAND);
```

The `||` operator is the logical OR operator. It actually gives you this:

```
0x8 /* MF_CHECKED */  ||  0x0 /* MF_BYCOMMAND */ == 0
```

Which is equivalent to `MF_UNCHECKED`.

Comment: @nidhal: Another possibility (and the one I first saw) is that you are creating and modifying a *new* `CMenu` object, which gets destroyed automatically as soon as it goes out of scope. You need to be modifying the *actual* menu in your application. There's not enough code posted in the question to actually see what is happening. Lots of variables are being used that are not declared.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ID_CONFIGURATION_DEFAULT instead of IDC_DEFAULTREMOVE in the statement popMenu.CheckMenuItem(IDC_DEFAULTREMOVE, MF_CHECKED || MF_BYCOMMAND);

ID_CONFIGURATION_DEFAULT - command ID
IDC_DEFAULTREMOVE - string resource ID